# How to fix my code in a simple Compsci 101 APT in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the problem we are given:

> Problem Statement
>
> You're a short-order cook in a pancake restaurant, so you need to cook pancakes as fast as possible. You have one pan that can fit capacity pancakes at a time. Using this pan you must cook numCakes pancakes. Each pancake must be cooked for five minutes on each side, and once a pancake starts cooking on a side it has to cook for five minutes on that side. However, you can take a pancake out of the pan when you're ready to flip it after five minutes and put it back in the pan later to cook it on the other side.
>   Write the method, minutesNeeded, that returns the shortest time needed to cook numCakes pancakes in a pan that holds capacity pancakes at once. See the examples.
>
> def minutesNeeded (numCakes, capacity):

I've tried various methods, and I've gotten it to work for most cases, but it doesn't always work because I don't know how to allow for the fact that sometimes you must take one off, start the side of another pancake, and then put one back on to finish.

```
def minutesNeeded (numCakes, capacity):
    #set some variables
    above = numCakes - capacity
    below = numCakes - above
    if numCakes <= capacity:
        time = numCakes * 10 / capacity
        return(int(time))
    else:
        time = below * 10 / capacity + above * 5
        return (int(time))
```

Lemme add an example:

```
import math

def minutesNeeded(numCakes, capacity):
    return (math.ceil(numCakes / capacity)) * 10
```

Here is an example: expected 15 got 20 : 3 2. It doesn't work because what you should do in this case is put two pancakes on for five minutes (cooking those sides), then take on pancake off and start the third cooking that third and the first for another five minutes. Now you have one cooked pancake and two pancakes that are half cooked. So you finish those two half cooked pancakes for another five minutes. Altogether you have spent 15 minutes and cooked three pancakes, but it did not take 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify an amount of time it takes to pour the batter, flip pancakes, or remove the pancakes, so for simplicity we'll assume those actions take zero time. So what do we know?

- The time it takes for a batch of pancakes is 10 minutes (5 minutes each side)
- The last batch, regardless of if the pan is at capacity, will still take 10 minutes

So what we need to do is take `numCakes` and divide by `capacity` to determine the number of batches needed, rounding up to make it an even number of batches. Then multiply the number of batches by 10 minutes:

```python
import math

def minutesNeeded(numCakes, capacity):
    return (math.ceil(numCakes / capacity)) * 10
```

**EDIT**

After being informed that there is a trick to this, I took a closer look. I believe I came up with a formula that works (and also no longer requires `math` module). Looking at the example of "need 3, capacity 2" I worked out an algorithm that gives the correct response while also working with other combinations.

```python
def minutesNeeded(numCakes, capacity):
    if numCakes == 0:
        return 0

    if numCakes <= capacity:
        return 10

    return int( ((numCakes * 2) + (capacity - 1)) / capacity ) * 5
```

Comment: So this would work, but it doesn't take into account certain things. Here is an example: expected 15 got 20 : 3 2. It doesn't work because what you should do in this case is put two pancakes on for five minutes (cooking those sides), then take on pancake off and start the third cooking that third and the first for another five minutes. Now you have one cooked pancake and two pancakes that are half cooked. So you finish those two half cooked pancakes for another five minutes. Altogether you have spent 15 minutes and cooked three pancakes, but it did not take 20 minutes.

Comment: @A.Doan Very interesting, I hadn't thought of that! Next we'll need a function to print out a list of minute-by-minute instructions for this poor chef =)

Comment: You probably want to add a check for the case where there are fewer cakes than there is capacity for (i.e. `return numCakes * 10`). With your current method, it will return `5` for some cases (such as 1 cake, 2 capacity), when the minimum bound is 10 (5 minutes per side).

Comment: Thanks, @b_c, I updated the sample code accordingly to handle that scenario.